# Searching from end of file using VIM

Tags: vim

How do I search from the end of file using VIM?  I want to search for the last occurrence of XXXX in the open file.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a range combined with searching backwards via `?`.

```
:1?XXXX
```

Overview:

- `1?XXXX` is the range.
- The `1` means first line of the file.
- `?XXXX` means search backwards from the first line (wrapping around) until you find the pattern `XXXX`

As ZyX mentioned this relies on `wrapscan` to be set, which it is by default. See `:h 'wrapscan'` for more information.

Answer (score 58):

Type `G$?XXXX`

- `G` to go to the end of the file
- `$` to go to the end of the line
- `?` to search backwards
- `XXXX` being what you want to search for

You could also do `gg?XXXX` which goes to the start of the file, then searches backwards, wrapping around to the end of the file.  However for large files it can be slow to seek to the start of the file and then immediately to the end of the file.

Answer (score 11):

go to last line using `G` and do backward search using `?XXXX`

Answer (score 7):

1)Use Vi editor

vi xx.log

2)Use `Shift + g`

3)for searching pattern 
 :?xxx

replace this xxx with  your search string.

4)`Shift + n`

for next search

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
gg?<string>
```

That will put the cursor at the the beginning of the file and perform a backward search. Since it will be impossible for vim to go *before* the cursor position, it will perform a search starting from the very end of the file.